# Why uninitialized global variable is weak symbol?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

It seems uninitialized global variable is treated as weak symbol in Gcc. What is the reason  behind this?

Comment: How do you come to that conclusion, what did you try, what are the facts?

Comment: C or C++? There's a big difference.

Comment: @AndreyT: In C, `int n;` at file scope is a tentative definition and it's a common extension (appendix J), which gcc follows, to allow multiple definitions both in a single translation unit (as in standard C) and between translation units so long as the definitions agree and at most one definition is not tentative. In C++ `int n;` is just a definition, there's no tentative concept, and it's not common to allow and merge multiple definitions in a program. The versions of gcc that I've used haven't allowed this in C++ mode, hence my questioning whether the C++ tag was really appropriate.

Comment: @AndreyT: I've just read your answer. Clearly you know all this already. Why bother to ask me and elicit the long explanation?

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Well, to me the concept of tentative definition appears to have only a local (restricted to one translation unit) effect and so it doesn't look like something relevant in this case. So, when it comes to inter-translation-unit issues (which this question seems to be about), I don't see any notable differences between C and C++ (aside from the "common extension" remark). The reason I asked is because I thought that maybe I'm missing something else.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**gcc, in C mode:**

Uninitialised globals which are not declared `extern` are treated as "common" symbols, not weak symbols.

Common symbols are merged at link time so that they all refer to the same storage; if more than one object attempts to initialise such a symbol, you will get a link-time error.  (If they aren't explicitly initialised anywhere, they will be placed in the BSS, i.e. initialised to 0.)

**gcc, in C++ mode:**

Not the same - it doesn't do the common symbols thing.  "Uninitialised" globals which are not declared `extern` are implicitly initialised to a default value (0 for simple types, or default constructor).

---

In either case, a weak symbol allows an initialised symbol to be overridden by a non-weak initialised symbol of the same name at link time.

---

To illustrate (concentrating on the C case here), I'll use 4 variants of a main program, which are all the same except for the way that `global` is declared:

1. **main_init.c**:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int global = 999;

   int main(void) { printf("%d\n", global); return 0; }
   ```
2. **main_uninit.c**, which omits the initialisation:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int global;

   int main(void) { printf("%d\n", global); return 0; }
   ```
3. **main_uninit_extern.c**, which adds the `extern` keyword:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   extern int global;

   int main(void) { printf("%d\n", global); return 0; }
   ```
4. **main_init_weak.c**, which initialises `global` and declares it to be a weak symbol:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int global __attribute__((weak)) = 999;

   int main(void) { printf("%d\n", global); return 0; }
   ```

and **another_def.c** which initialises the same global:

```
int global = 1234;
```

---

Using `main_uninit.c` on its own gives 0:

```
$ gcc -o test main_uninit.c && ./test
0
```

but when `another_def.c` is included as well, `global` is explicitly initialised and we get the expected result:

```
$ gcc -o test main_uninit.c another_def.c && ./test
1234
```

(Note that this case fails instead if you're using C++.)

If we try with both `main_init.c` and `another.def.c` instead, we have 2 initialisations of `global`, which won't work:

```
$ gcc -o test main_init.c another_def.c && ./test
/tmp/cc5DQeaz.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `global'
/tmp/ccgyz6rL.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

`main_uninit_extern.c` on its own won't work at all - the `extern` keyword causes the symbol to be an ordinary external reference rather than a common symbol, so the linker complains:

```
$ gcc -o test main_uninit_extern.c && ./test
/tmp/ccqdYUIr.o: In function `main':
main_uninit_extern.c:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `global'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It works fine once the initialisation from `another_def.c` is included:

```
$ gcc -o test main_uninit_extern.c another_def.c && ./test
1234
```

---

Using `main_init_weak.c` on its own gives the value we initialised the weak symbol to (999), as there is nothing to override it:

```
$ gcc -o test main_init_weak.c && ./test
999
```

But pulling in the other definition from `another_def.c` does work in this case, because the strong definition there overrides the weak definition in `main_init_weak.c`:

```
$ gcc -o test main_init_weak.c another_def.c && ./test
1234
```

Comment: Great explanation with examples. Could you also include how weak interacts with functions?

Comment: @Maciej - good point, forgot this was tagged with both when writing my answer originally!  No, it's not the same for C++, so I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Tomek - weak functions are similar: if the linker sees both a weak definition of a function and a strong (normal) one, it will resolve any undefined references to the strong one, and ignore the weak one.  If it only sees a weak definition, it will use that as if it were a normal one.

Comment: This explanation can be taken as the description of the specific compiler behavior. It is **incorrect** as the description of C language behavior. C language *prohibits* multiple definitions of entities with external linkage (just like C++ does). The behavior observed is nothing more than a compiler extension.

Comment: Additionally, it should be noted that in C, just like in C++, uninitialized global variables are implicitly initialized with 0. For some reason, the wording in the answer above seems to present it as a difference between C and C++.

Comment: @AndreyT right, but the question is specifically asking about gcc and weak symbols, it's a linker/compiler/implementation question, not a language question and this is an appropriate answer imo.

Comment: @Logan Capaldo: I agree, the answer is appropriate. Maybe I just misunderstood the "In C" and "In C++" captions. Were they meant to refer to "GCC in C mode" and "GCC in C++ mode"?

Comment: @AndreyT: yes (as the question is very specifically asking about GCC).  I guess it read better before I edited earlier to note the C vs. C++ difference.  I've edited again to clarify that I'm talking about GCC. (Regarding your other point: I did also originally say that uninitialised common symbols end up in the BSS.  I've moved that to the top as well.)

Answer (score 10):

The question is based on an incorrect premise. Uninitialized global variables are not weak symbols.

Apparently the question is referring to the ability to define the same uninitialized object with external linkage in multiple translation units. Formally, it is not allowed - it is an error in both C and C++. However, at least in C is recognized by C99 standard as "common extension" of the language, implemented in many real-life compilers

> **J.5 Common extensions**
>
> **J.5.11 Multiple external definitions**
>
> **1** There may be more than one external
> definition for the identifier of an
> object, with or without the explicit
> use of the keyword extern; if the
> definitions disagree, or more than one
> is initialized, the behavior is
> undefined (6.9.2).

Note, that contrary to the popular belief, C language explicitly prohibits introducing multiple definitions of entities with external linkage in the program, just like C++ does.

> **6.9 External definitions**
>
> **5** An external definition is an
> external declaration that is also a
> definition of a function (other than
> an inline definition) or an object. If
> an identifier declared with external
> linkage is used in an expression
> (other than as part of the operand of
> a sizeof operator whose result is an
> integer constant), somewhere in the
> entire program there shall be **exactly
> one** external definition for the
> identifier; otherwise, there shall be
> **no more than one**.

However, the extension allowing this has been pretty popular with many C compilers, of which GCC just happens to be one.

Comment: The supporting linker feature is required in order to implement FORTRAN common blocks. You will notice that GCC does include a FORTRAN compiler in the collection. Since the supporting libraries are implemented in C, it is no surprise that there is a small amount of harmless leakage back from the linker.

Comment: Can you give an example of external definition and external declaration?

Comment: It's not just FORTRAN, C++ inline functions and implicitly instantiated templates are also weak.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you meant?

weak.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int weak; /* global, weak, zero */

int main(void) {
  printf("weak value is %d.\n", weak);
  return 0;
}
```

strong.c

```
int weak = 42; /* global, strong, 42 */
```

Sample run

```
$ gcc weak.c
$ ./a.out
weak value is 0.
$ gcc weak.c strong.c
$ ./a.out
weak value is 42.
```

<s>**The `int weak;` in weak.c is a declaration, not a definition.** Or you may say it's a tentative definition. **The real definition is in `strong.c` when that object file is linked in the final program** or in `weak.c` otherwise.</s>
This is a common extension, one that gcc uses (thanks Andrey).

Comment: Not true. `int weak` in `weak.c` is a definition. A tentative one, but definition nevertheless. The program above *does* violate the rules of the language, yet is supported as a non-standard extension.

Comment: For an explanation of why you nowadays get a "multiple definition" linker error with the above code, see the comment from @IanAbbott in response to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75080487/gnu-linker-no-longer-overrides-weak-symbols (and see also the note about "common" symbols in the accepted answer to this question).

Answer (score 3):

Any multiple definition of a global symbol is undefined behavior, so gcc (or rather the GNU binutils linker) is free to do whatever it wants. In practice, it follows the traditional behavior to avoid breaking code that relies on this behavior.

Comment: Do you mean multiple **definition** ?