# Usage of extern in the same file

Tags: c, linker, extern

I am confused with the usage of `extern` in the same file as shown in the code below. The first case was actually a solution to print a global variable in C (when same name local variable exist), but I am not able to understand how that worked and how the third case didn't work.

Case 1:

```
int a = 10;
int main()
{
    int a = 20;
    {
        extern int a; // Is this telling the linker to use global variable? 
        printf("A value: %d\n", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Case 2:

```
extern int a; // If in the above case extern was telling linker to use global variable 
              // then how in this local variable is getting referred
int main()
{
    int a = 20;
    {
        printf("A value: %d\n", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Case 3:

```
// int a = 10;
int main()
{
    int a = 20;
    {
         extern int a; // Why now I get a linking error
         printf("A value: %d\n", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335742/can-local-and-register-variables-be-declared-extern

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first case you have a global `a` that you override with a local (automatic) `a` that you again override with the global `a` (extern can only refer to variables global in some module). It will print `10`.

In the second case you have a global `a`, that resides in this or in another module (c file/compilation unit) that you override with a local `a`. It will print `20`.

In the third case you have a local `a` that you override with a global `a` that apparently does not exist in any of your compilation units, hence the linker error.

Comment: The global `a` does not have to reside in another translation unit.  A single `extern int a;` at file scope is sufficient to define the object per the tentative definition rule of **6.9.2 External object definitions**, paragraph 2.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `C99` draft says, that "A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and
without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a
tentative definition." Nothing is said about `extern` specifier, so `extern int a;` is not a tentative definition. I couldn't figure out whether standard considers it undefined behaviour, but in case of `gcc` refering to such variable (without any definition at any translation unit) yields a linker error.

Comment: @Przemek If "Nothing is said about `extern` specifier", how can you conclude "`extern int a;` is not a tentative definition."?

Comment: Since `extern` is a storage class specifier, `extern int a;` at file scope is not a tentative definition.  It is an unused and undefined declaration.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Because there is no sentence implying that. Furthermore, behaviour of `extern int a;` is similar in block and in global scope - if there is no definition, it fails to link. This behaviour is exactly opposite to a tentative definition.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler this is how it works in practice, but is it specified by the standard?

Comment: @Przemek: [C11 §6.9.2 ¶2 External object definitions](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.2p2): _A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a tentative definition._ When the compiler sees `extern int a;` at file scope, it is a declaration of an identifier without an initializer but **with** a storage class specifier (`extern`), so it is **not** a 'tentative definition'. To be a tentative definition, it would have to be `int a;` or `static int a;`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Your first comment in this sequence contradicts what the standard says.  The `extern int a;` at file scope is categorically not a 'tentative definition'.

Answer (score 4):

(Note that the edits to the code in the question seem to make parts of this answer no longer quite correct.)

Per **6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers**, paragraph 4 of [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier `extern`
>   in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible,
>   if the prior declaration specifies internal or external  linkage,  **the
>   linkage  of  the  identifier  at  the  later  declaration  is  the 
>   same  as  the linkage specified at the prior declaration.**

So, in your first two cases, the inner `extern int a;` has a prior declaration - a global `int a;` in your first case or `extern int a;` in your second case - so the `extern int a;` declaration refers to the global.

For the third case, the remainder of paragraph 4 is relevant:

> If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior
>   declaration specifies no linkage, then **the identifier has external linkage**.

Also, paragraph 6 states:

> The following identifiers have no linkage: an identifier declared to be anything other than
>   an  object  or  a  function;  an  identifier  declared  to  be  a  function  parameter;  **a  block  scope
>   identifier for an object declared without the storage-class specifier
>   `extern`.**

So the declaration in your third case is referring to an `extern int a;`

However, there is no actual `int a;` defined anywhere. And because the `extern int a;` in your third example appears in a block scope, and there is no actual definition of the `int a;` object elsewhere, your program fails to link.

Per **6.9.2  External object definitions**, paragraph 2 states:

> **A declaration  of  an  identifier  for  an  object  that  has  file  scope**  without  an  initializer, and
>   without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier
>   `static`, constitutes a
>   tentative definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an
>   identifier, and  the  translation  unit  contains  no  external  definition  for  that  identifier, then
>   the  behavior  is  exactly  as  if  the  translation  unit  contains  a  file  scope  declaration  of  that
>   identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer
>   equal to 0.

So the block-scope `extern int a;` declaration of your third case does not qualify as a tentative definition.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1:**

The `extern int a ;` declaration declares a `int a` variable that is defined elsewhere and thus shadowing the `a` variable declared here : `int a = 20 ;`. The linker is then looking for a global variable `a` and finds it in the same file because of the `int a = 10 ;` declaration. The output is `10`.

**Case 2:**

Here the `extern int a ;` declaration has no effect. Inside `main` the local variable declared here `int a = 20 ;` is used and hence the output is `20`.

**Case 3:**

This is similar to case 1. It does compile correctly, but is does not link because `extern int a ;` declares a `int a` variable that is presumably defined elsewhere, which is not the case because you commented out the `int a = 10 ;` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1:-**  In first code block `extern int a;` indicates that variable `a` is declared here but tells linker to find the definition of `a` above `main()` not in the `main()`. If linker is able to find the definition of `a` above `main()` then it will link otherwise results in linker error. In your case linker will take `a` as `10`.

**Case 2 :-** In this case above globally declared `extern int a;` is telling to linker that definition of `a` may be in other file or in the same file in the `main()` function. Here `extern int a;` is saying that if you need it, there will be a definition of a with *static duration and external linkage* (`a` global variable) defined either in *this file* or *in another file*. That declaration is hidden by the definition inside `main()`, so the `printf()` uses the `local variable`. 
This

`printf("A value: %d\n",a);`

consider locally declared `a`. So it prints `20`.

**Case 3 :-** In this case the statement

```
extern int a; // Why now I get a linking error
```

causing linker error because linker will try to find definition of `a` above `main()` and it's not there(you commented) so it's results in *linker error*.

Comment: In case 2, the `extern int a;` is saying that if you need it, there will be a definition of `a` with static duration and external linkage (a 'global variable') defined either in this file or in another file.  That declaration is hidden by the definition inside `main()`, so the `printf()` uses the local variable — and it is immaterial whether the global variable exists since it is not used.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler for pointing that. It's very useful information for me.