# Is it valid to use extern in a local scope to unshadow a global variable?

Tags: c++, global-variables, extern, local-variables

Is this `extern` declaration in a nested local scope a valid and defined way to bring the global `a` back into the scope?

```
int a = 1; // may be in another file
void main() {
    int a = 2; // hides the global
    {
     cout << a << endl;  // prints 2
     cout << ::a << endl; // obviously 1
     extern int a;
     cout << a << endl;  // also prints 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can local and register variables be declared extern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335742/can-local-and-register-variables-be-declared-extern)

Comment: Actually the question that you linked has conflicting answers. Some say yes, some say no.

Answer (score 5):

This is a valid use of `extern`, though an obscure one. According to the C++20 standard ([basic.link]/6):

> The name of a function declared in block scope and the name of a variable declared by a block scope
> `extern` declaration have linkage. If such a declaration is attached to a named module, the program is
> ill-formed. If there is a visible declaration of an entity with linkage, ignoring entities declared outside the
> innermost enclosing namespace scope, such that the block scope declaration would be a (possibly ill-formed)
> redeclaration if the two declarations appeared in the same declarative region, the block scope declaration
> declares that same entity and receives the linkage of the previous declaration. If there is more than one such
> matching entity, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, if no matching entity is found, the block scope entity
> receives external linkage. If, within a translation unit, the same entity is declared with both internal and
> external linkage, the program is ill-formed.

In the OP's example, the block-scope declaration `extern int a;` fails to find a matching declaration with linkage, because the local declaration `int a = 2;` which has no linkage hides the global declaration `int a = 1;` which has external linkage. Therefore, `extern int a;` defaults to external linkage. Also see paragraph 7:

> When a block scope declaration of an entity with linkage is not found to refer to some other declaration,
> then that entity is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. However such a declaration does not
> introduce the member name in its namespace scope.

Therefore, `extern int a;` declares `a` as a member of the nearest enclosing namespace, which is the global namespace. This means it's the same entity as the previously declared global `a`, since both declare a variable with the same name in the same namespace with linkage. In other words, it gives you a way to refer to the global variable within the block.

This use of `extern` was inherited from C, but it is obscure even in C. Its use should generally be avoided in favour of `::a`.