# extern storage class output

Tags: c, extern, storage-class-specifier

so**my question is,**
**Is there two variable named x in the main ,one goes to g() with value 1 go there prints 2 and another one keeps at 1 again prints 2 in main. **

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f(){
    extern int x;
    
    x++;
    printf("%d",x);
    
}
  int x;
void g(){
   
    ++x;
    printf("%d",x);
}
int main() {
    // Write C code here
    x++;
    g();
    
    printf("%d",x);

    return 0;
}
```

> Output : 22

Comment: There's only one single global variable `x` in the shown code. It's initialized to zero by the system (global non-constant variables are always "zero" initialized). It's increased to `1` in the `main` function. It's increased to `2` in the `g` function. The `g` function prints its value. Then the `main` function print its value.

Comment: In the future, please try to use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code, line by line while monitoring variables and their values, to see what's really is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `x` in main and the one defined outside g() in global scope are referring to the same `x`. Also the variable `x` is `extern` through out the code because of the previous declaration.

Try printing the address of `x` in the required location.

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30932839/4402433) for more info

Answer (score 0):

> Is there two variable named x in the main

No, there is only ***one*** and it has static storage duration. It was defined just above the `g()` function definition.

You could check it yourself by adding something to your `printf`s:

```
void f(void)
{
    extern int x;
    
    x++;
    printf("%d %p\n", x, (void *)&x);
}

int x;

void g(void)
{
    ++x;
    printf("%d %p\n", x, (void *)&x);
}

int main(void) 
{
    x++;
    g();
    printf("%d %p\n", x, (void *)&x);
}
```

and the output:

```
2 0x40401c
2 0x40401c
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sxYnfzqhP