# Different objects in c++

Tags: c++, object

This program displays different types of object in c++ using constructor. I have attached a snapshot of the output. In the output, why isn't there a message displayed for the creation of the extern object?

```
//Program to illustrate different type of objects
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
class diffobjs{
    public:
    char msg[10];
    diffobjs(char ar[]){
        strcpy(msg,ar);
        cout<<"\nObject created of type "<<msg;
    }
    ~diffobjs(){
        cout<<"\n"<<msg<<" object destroyed";
        getch();
    }
};
extern diffobjs d1("Global");
void main(){
    clrscr();
    diffobjs d2("Automatic");
    static diffobjs d3("Static");
    getch();
}
```

[image: OUTPUT:]

Comment: your program is not a c++ program, please reformulate your question.

Comment: remove the clrscr();

Comment: @user2485710... So what is your definition of C++?

Comment: @DieterLücking you're right but still a bit enigmatic. extern object is initialized BEFORE entering main function. So simply your output is cleared out by clrscr

Comment: @sgar91 I imagine something that conforms to one of the standards. I would say C++11, but some still take it to mean C++03. In any case, this code is neither.

Comment: It's pre-standard C++, lots of compilers will still accept that, and it's certainly not any other language. Arguing over this is not helpful to actually answering the question.

Comment: What is the compiler version?

Comment: @MatthewWalton My g++ just choked on the code. Only 7 errors, and 3 warnings.

Comment: The flavour of C++ you are using went out of date in 1998. Perhaps you want to update your textbook.

Answer (score 2):

Fixing some issues:

```
//Program to illustrate different type of objects

// Standard C++ headers have no .h
#include<iostream>

// Not portable
// #include<conio.h>

// This <string.h> and other C headers are replaced by c... headers
// #include<cstring>


class diffobjs{
    public:
    // Have a std std::string to avoid buffer overflows
    std::string msg;
    diffobjs(const std::string& s)
    //  Use initialization
    :   msg(s)
    {
        std::cout<<"Object created of type "<<msg<<'\n';
    }
    ~diffobjs() {
        std::cout<<msg<<" object destroyed"<<'\n';
    }
};

// A declaration would go in a header
extern diffobjs d1;

// The definition is without 'extern'
diffobjs d1("Global");

int main(){
    // Globals are initialized before main
    // Remove the non-portable clrscr();
    // clrscr();
    std::cout << "\n[Entering Main]\n\n";
    diffobjs d2("Automatic [1]");
    // A static in a function is initialized only once, the static has an impact on
    // the order of destruction.
    static diffobjs d3("Static");
    // Added
    diffobjs d4("Automatic [2]");
    // You might not see destruction, if you start the programm in your IDE
    // Hence, remove the non-portable getch()
    // getch();
    std::cout << "\n[Leaving Main]\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line with the extern keyword does not define the object, but only forward declares it. If you remove this keyword and leave the rest of the line, a global object will be created.

Answer (score 0):

"extern" Keyword  just declares  object it won't define.

[Why do we need the 'extern' keyword in C if file scope declarations have external linkage by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300239/why-we-need-extern-keyword-in-c)