# Declaring global variables in the header file or the C source file

Tags: c, header-files

I am kind of confused about the whole including header files and declaration of variables.

Files I am using are: main.c, lib.h and lib.c.

#### main.c

```
#include "lib.h"

void main(void)
{
    // Code here
    var++;
}
```

#### lib.c

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "lib.h"

void light_led(void)
{
    // Code here
}
```

#### lib.h

```
volatile int var;

void light_led(void);
```

Is this the correct way of making and including your own custom-made libraries?

Comment: no. that's not a declaration, that's a definition (this will cause a linker error).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `extern` keyword for such cases and not define global variables in headers. Otherwise the linker will throw errors when operating on your header files.

**lib.c**

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "lib.h"

volatile int var;

void light_led(void)
{
//code here
}
```

**lib.h**

```
extern volatile int var;

void light_led(void);
```

This way you'll be declaring the global variable in headers and actually defining it in the appropriate source file `lib.c`.

**Note:** Notice the difference between declaring and defining a variable. `extern` keyword allows the variable to be declared in advance without being defined. Had you not defined the variable in `lib.c`, there would be an error when you tried to use this variable. Since, it is only **declared** but, not actually **defined**.

**Edit:** The whole purpose of `static` is to declare that a variable is private to the source file that is declared in. Since, `extern` does the opposite by linking a variable defined in another source file, it defeats the purpose of `static`. `extern` says the variable has external linkage `static` says the variable has internal linkage. An identifier can't have both internal and external linkage.

According to [MSND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> When modifying a variable, the static keyword specifies that the variable has static duration (it is allocated when the program begins and deallocated when the program ends) and initializes it to 0 unless another value is specified. **When modifying a variable or function at file scope, the static keyword specifies that the variable or function has internal linkage (its name is not visible from outside the file in which it is declared).**

For more information check below:

- [Understanding "extern" keyword in C](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/)
- [Why we need "extern keyword in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300239/why-we-need-extern-keyword-in-c)

Comment: As long as you're editing this, don't forget the semicolon at the end.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize the OP omitted one in his code.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't notice that.

Comment: @TamerTas Thank you for the explanation. So basically 'extern' keyword makes the variable global and so that implies that the keywords 'extern' and 'static' would never be used together as they would mean the opposite things, correct?