# "multiple definition of value" when compiling C program with uninitialized global in g++ but not gcc

Tags: c++, c, linker, compiler-errors, global-variables

I'm trying to understand the usage of extern and global variable declaration in header files so I came up with the following test program written in C.

The main.c file

```
//main.c
#include "global.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int nExternValue = 6;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("%d \n", nValue);
    printf("%d \n", nExternValue);

    AddToValue();

    printf("%d \n", nValue);
    printf("%d \n", nExternValue);
}
```

The global.h file

```
#ifndef _GLOBAL_H
#define _GLOBAL_H

//WRONG! do not declare a variable here
int nValue;

//OK! extern variable makes it a global accessable variable
extern int nExternValue;

//OK! function prototype can be placed in h file
int AddToValue();

#endif
```

and a AddValue.c file which implements the AddToValue function.

```
#include "global.h"

int AddToValue() {
    nValue++;
    nExternValue++;
}
```

I compiled the app using gcc, AND ran it:

```
$ gcc main.c AddValue.c -o test
$./test
0 
6 
1 
7
```

I complied the app using g++ and got the following linker error:

```
$ g++ main.c AddValue.c -o test
/tmp/ccFyGDYM.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `nValue'
/tmp/cc3ixXdu.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why doesn't the gcc linker produce an error? I though the nValue variable would be declared multiple times and that would produce an error!

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: when you include a *.h file in serveral *.c files you will be declaring several times the same variable. To  avoid this is better not to declare global variables in a *.h file but instead in a *.c file.

Comment: @Kira I think the question here is **why gcc linker does not produce the multiple declaration as an error?**

Comment: @shinkou indeed, but that's why I made a comment and not an answer just in case he needs to fix the problem while he waits for true answers.

Comment: Thanks Kira, but I didn't think you should declare global variables in .c file. How would other files know about the declared variable if it's in the .c file, unless you are suggesting to #include the .c file?

Comment: @ArmenB. -- Look up "tentative declaration".  That should answer your question.

Comment: @ArmenB. use `extern` in the file that needs the global variable for that matter. Here http://pastebin.com/irfsGrMq I made an example for you to try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C and C++ are different languages. Case in point, the above program is a valid C program but in ill-formed C++ program. You have violated C++'s one definition rule. There is no corresponding rule in C.

When compiling with gcc, you are compiling the above text as a C program. When compiling with g++, you are compiling the above text as a C++ program.

Comment: AnT said it is also invalid C, although a common extension mentioned in Annex J: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3692486/895245

Comment: C has a one-definition rule and the program is not a valid C program either. (There are two definitions for `nValue`).

Answer (score 4):

When compiled with gcc, uninitialized global variable (such as nValue) will be treated as a common symbol. The same common symbol occurred in different compilation unit will be merged during link time. If compiled with g++ (which means that the source program will be treated as C++ program), uninitialized global variable are implicitly initialized with a default value 0. Since global.h is included in multiple source files, the compiler will consider the symbol nValue defined multiple times.

Please also have a look at this post:
[Why uninitialized global variable is weak symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691835/why-uninitialized-global-variable-is-weak-symbol)