# __attribute__ ((weak)) not work for global variable

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, weak-symbol

```
pqy@localhost ~/src/test/a $ cat m.c
#include <stdio.h>
int aaaaa __attribute__ ((weak)) =8;
int main(void){
    printf("%d\n", aaaaa);
    return 0;
}
pqy@localhost ~/src/test/a $ cat lib.c
int aaaaa = 5;

pqy@localhost ~/src/test/a $ gcc lib.c -fPIC -shared -o libb.so;gcc m.c -o m -L. -lb -Wl,-rpath=$PWD;./m
8
```

Above is my code and test result. I am confused why it does not work as expected.

Also try function, not work ether. Below is the test result.

```
pqy@localhost ~/src/test/a $ cat lib.c
int fun() {
    return 5;
}
pqy@localhost ~/src/test/a $ cat m.c
#include <stdio.h>
__attribute__((weak)) int fun() {
    return 8;
}
int main(void){
    printf("%d\n", fun());
    return 0;
}
pqy@localhost ~/src/test/a $ gcc lib.c -fPIC -shared -o libb.so;gcc m.c -O0 -o m -L. -lb -Wl,-rpath=$PWD;./m
8
pqy@localhost ~/src/test/a $ ldd m
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd819ec000)
        libb.so => /home/pqy/src/test/a/libb.so (0x00007f7226738000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7226533000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7226744000)
pqy@localhost ~/src/test/a $
```

Comment: What does `ldd ./m` show? Does it show `libb.so` being loaded?

Comment: Yes. libb.so has been loaded

Comment: I believe there are multiple definitions of the variable. Each translation unit only sees its own copy. `main` sees the strong one, and weak sees the weak one. You should probably re-run your tests with a global variable declared `extern` in all translation units. Also see [How to make weak linking work with GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274753/608639), [Why uninitialized global variable is weak symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3692077/608639)  and [Strong and Weak Symbols in GCC](https://leondong1993.github.io/2017/04/15/strong-weak-symbol/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At bottom what you have observed here is just the fact that the linker will not
resolve a symbol dynamically if it can resolve it statically. See:

**main.c**

```
extern void foo(void);
extern void need_dynamic_foo(void);
extern void need_static_foo(void);

int main(void){
    foo();
    need_dynamic_foo();
    need_static_foo();
    return 0;
}
```

**dynamic_foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    puts("foo (dynamic)");
}

void need_dynamic_foo(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

**static_foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    puts("foo (static)");
}

void need_static_foo(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

Compile the sources so:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c main.c static_foo.c
$ gcc -Wall -fPIC -c dynamic_foo.c
```

Make a shared library:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libfoo.so dynamic_foo.o
```

And link a program:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o static_foo.o libfoo.so -Wl,-rpath=$PWD
```

It runs like:

```
$ ./prog
foo (static)
need_dynamic_foo
need_static_foo
```

So `foo` and `need_static_foo` were statically resolved to the definitions from `static_foo.o` and
the definition of `foo` from `libfoo.so` was ignored, despite the fact that `libfoo.so`
*was* needed and provided the definition of `need_dynamic_foo`. It makes no difference
if we change the linkage order to:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o libfoo.so static_foo.o -Wl,-rpath=$PWD
$ ./prog
foo (static)
need_dynamic_foo
need_static_foo
```

It also makes no difference if we replace `static_foo.c` with:

**static_weak_foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void __attribute__((weak)) foo(void)
{
    puts("foo (static weak)");
}

void need_static_foo(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

Compile that and relink:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c static_weak_foo.c
$ gcc -o prog main.o libfoo.so static_weak_foo.o -Wl,-rpath=$PWD
$ ./prog
foo (static weak)
need_dynamic_foo
need_static_foo
```

Although the definition of `foo` in `static_weak_foo.c` is now declared weak,
the fact that `foo` *can* be statically resolved to this definition
still preempts any need to resolve it dynamically.

Now if we write another source file containing another strong definition of
`foo`:

**static_strong_foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    puts("foo (static strong)");
}
```

and compile it and link as follows:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c static_strong_foo.c
$ gcc -o prog main.o static_weak_foo.o libfoo.so static_strong_foo.o -Wl,-rpath=$PWD
```

we see:

```
$ ./prog
foo (static strong)
need_dynamic_foo
need_static_foo
```

Now, `libfoo.so` still provides the definition of `need_dynamic_foo`, because there
is no other; `static_weak_foo.o` still provides the only definition of `need_static_foo`,
and the definition of `foo` in `libfoo.so` is still ignored because the symbol
can be statically resolved.

But in this case there are two definitions of `foo` in different files that are
available to resolve it statically: the weak definition in `static_weak_foo.o` and
the strong definition in `static_strong_foo.o`. By the linkage rules that you are
familiar with, the strong definition wins.

If both of these statically linked definitions of `foo` were strong, there would of course be a
multiple definition error, just like:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o static_foo.o libfoo.so static_strong_foo.o -Wl,-rpath=$PWD
static_strong_foo.o: In function `foo':
static_strong_foo.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `foo'
static_foo.o:static_foo.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

in which the dynamic definition in `libfoo.so` *plays no part*. So you can
be guided by this practical principle: The rules you are familiar with for arbitrating
between weak and strong definitions of the same symbol in a linkage only apply
to rival definitions *which would provoke a multiple definition error in the absence
of the* `weak` *attribute*.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol is resolved at link stage, during the link stage only the weak symbol `aaaaa = 8` is visible.

If the symbol can be resolved in the link stage, it won't generate a relocation entry, then nothing will happen at load stage

There are no `aaaaa` in the relocation table:

```
% objdump -R m         

m:     file format elf64-x86-64

DYNAMIC RELOCATION RECORDS
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE 
0000000000003dc8 R_X86_64_RELATIVE  *ABS*+0x0000000000001130
0000000000003dd0 R_X86_64_RELATIVE  *ABS*+0x00000000000010f0
0000000000004028 R_X86_64_RELATIVE  *ABS*+0x0000000000004028
0000000000003fd8 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
0000000000003fe0 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000003fe8 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  __gmon_start__
0000000000003ff0 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000003ff8 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000004018 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT  printf@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

Comment: I also link with libb.so, which has aaaaa=5, why aaaa=5 is not visible at link stage?

Comment: @MrPang The symbol is linked against **definition**, shared library only provides **declaration**, Only the actual object and static-library provide definitions. shared library provides definitions at load stage.

Answer (score 0):

Сompiler or linker builds files from the command line in reverse order. In other words, files with ((weak)) should be located earlier in the command line than dynamic ones.